# How to upload custom web page on parse backend for email verification

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I want to change look and feel of parse email verification page but unable to upload custom web page on parse backend, how can i upload and change look and feel of email verification process page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you got now?

Comment: i am new in parse and i want to upload custom web page on parse backend for email verification.